# fopen Segfault error on large files

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fopen

Hello everyone I'm new to C but I've recently been getting a weird segfault error with my fopen.

```
   FILE* thefile = fopen(argv[1],"r");
```

The problem I've been having is that this code works on other smaller text files, but when I try with a file around 400MB it will give a sefault error. I've even tried hardcoding the filename but that doesn't work either. Could there be a problem in the rest of the code causing the segfault on this line?(doubt it but would like to know if its possible. It's just really odd that no errors come up for a small text file, but a large text file does get errors.

Thanks!

EDIT* didn't want to bog this down with too much but heres my code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 if(argc != 3)
{
printf("[ERROR] Invalid number of arguments. Please pass 2 arguments, input_bound_file (column  1:probe, columne 2,...: samples) and desired_output_file_name");
exit(2);
}

int i,j;
rankAvg= g_hash_table_new(g_direct_hash, g_direct_equal);
rankCnt= g_hash_table_new(g_direct_hash, g_direct_equal);
table = g_hash_table_new_full (g_direct_hash, g_direct_equal, NULL, g_free);
getCounts(argv[1]);
printf("NC=: %i       nR =: %i",nC,nR);
double srcMat[nR][nC];
int rankMat[nR][nC];
double normMat[nR][nC];
int sorts[nR][nC];
char line[100];

FILE* thefile = fopen(argv[1],"r");
printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
FILE* output = fopen(argv[2],"w");
char* rownames[100];
i=0;j = 1;
int processedProbeNumber = 0;
int previousStamp = 0;
fgets(line,sizeof(line),thefile); //read file

while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),thefile) != NULL)
{
cleanSpace(line); //creates only one space between entries
  char dest[100];
  int len = strlen(line);
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    if(line[i] == ' ') //read in rownames
    {
    rownames[j] = strncpy(dest, line, i);
    dest[i] = '\0';
    break;
    }
  }

  char* token = strtok(line, " ");
  token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  i=1;

  while(token!=NULL) //put words into array
    {
    rankMat[j][i]= abs(atof(token));
      srcMat[j][i] = abs(atof(token));
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
    }

    // set the first column as a row id
    j++;
  processedProbeNumber++;

    if( (processedProbeNumber-previousStamp) >= 10000)
    {
      previousStamp = processedProbeNumber;
      printf("\tnumber of loaded lines = %i",processedProbeNumber);

    }
}
printf("\ttotal number of loaded lines  = %i \n",processedProbeNumber);
fclose(thefile);
```

Comment: You probably need to post more of the actual code. E.g. do you check the result of fopen to see whether it's != NULL ?

Comment: OOC: What platform are you running on?

Comment: @howard: Add this code after `fopen` and tell us what the output is: `printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));` (you may also need to add `#include` statements for `<string.h>` and `<errno.h>` if you don't already have them).

Comment: I tried adding the code but nothing was printed when I used the small file. When  I used the larger file it didn't print anything because the segfault comes right before?

Also how could it be null? I didn't think that was possible especailly since I hardcoded it and it works with the smaller file?

Comment: It may not print before the segfault because stdout is buffered. Try `fprintf(stderr, ...)` instead of `printf()` or add a `fflush(stdout)` right after the `printf()`.

Comment: I think you need a debugger, any good one will tell you where the segfault originates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that `fopen` is seg faulting?  If you're simply sprinkling `printf` in the code, there's a chance the standard output isn't sent to the console before the error occurs.  Obviously, if you're using a debugger you will know exactly where the segfault occured.

Looking at your code, `nR` and `nC` aren't defined so I don't know how big `rankMat` and `srcMat` are, but two thoughts crossed my mind while looking at your code:

- You don't check `i` and `j` to ensure that they don't exceed `nR` and `nC`
- If `nR` and `nC` are sufficiently large, that may mean you're using a very large amount of memory on the stack (`srcMat`, `rankMat`, `normMat`, and `sorts` are all huge).  I don't know what environemnt you're running in, but some systems my not be able to handle huge stacks (Linux, Windows, etc. should be fine, but I do a lot of embedded work).  I normally allocate very large structures in the heap (using `malloc`).

Comment: the gdb debugger says the segfault occurs when opening the file, but I'll look for checking for nR and nC. Both of those are dynamically allocated based on row and column length

Comment: okay well I checked it before accessing the array element by checking j<nR, still get a segfault and backtrace says its the open line :/

Comment: I tried adding a printf statement before the accessing and then it segfaulted on the print statement, so that must mean the problem is running out of memory correct? I am using ubuntu

Comment: Yes, you could very well be running out of memory. I recommend that you malloc srcMat, rankMat, normalMat, and sorts and make sure malloc doesn't return NULL. Also, it wouldn't hurt to use the debugger to determine what nC and nR are, because they may be huge and you don't realize how much memory you're actually using (bytes used = nC * nR * 24, across all four arrays).

Comment: yes I did go ahead and malloc them, and in the larger files the nR is getting up to around 20k  so more things I got to figure  out but thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

400Mb should not be considered a "large file" nowadays. I would reserve this for files larger than, say, 2Gb.

Also, just opening a file is very unlikely to give a segfault. WOuld you show us the code that access the file? I suspect some other factor is at play here.

*UPDATE*

I still can't tell exactly what's happening here. There are strange things that could be legitimate: you discard the first line and also the first token of each line.

You also assign to all the `rownames[j]` (except the first one) the address of `dest` which is a variable that has a block scope and whose associated memory is most likely to be reused outside that block. I hope you don't rely on `rownames[j]` to be any meaningful (but then why you have them?) and you never try to access them.

C99 allows you to mix variable declarations with actual instructions but I would suggest a little bit of cleaning to make the code clearer (also a better indentation would help).

From the symptoms I would look for some memory corruption somewhere. On small files (and hence less tokens) it may go unnoticed, but with larger files (and many more token) it fires a segfault.

Comment: Just did it, I'm still new to C so if something looks off please let me know

Comment: okay I will look into the variables and see whats going on. And rownames and the header were supposed to be added on later, i was more focused on doing matrix manipulations of the data and forgot to sort those two out. One of my friends offered the suggestion that fopen isnt usable for files over 100mb, is that true? Thanks!

Comment: Don't trust your friend, a 100Mb file is absolutely fine! Look at Klox answer, he's right, you don't check that j stays less than nR!

Answer (score 1):

Generally files 2GB (2**31) or larger are the ones you can expect to get this on. This is because you are starting to run out of space in a 32-bit integer for things like file indices, and one bit is typically taken up for directions in relative offsets.

Supposedly on Linux you can get around this issue by using the following macro defintion:

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
```

Some systems also provide a separate API call for large file opens (eg: `fopen64()` in [MKS](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/fopen.3.asp)).